# Automated testing of AWS IAM policies

Tags: junit, permissions, automated-tests, amazon-iam

We have number of roles with attached policies to them in AWS IAM. It's easy to test those roles can do expected actions on expected resources.

I wonder how do we create negative scenarios to verify that those roles can't do any other actions than specified? We'd like to automate these tests, possibly as JUnits with AWS policy simulator, and ensure that some future combination of different policies doesn't give an unexpected permission.

It seems to me, that to be 100% sure, you'd have to test all possible actions on the role. But isn't that too excessive approach? Should we be happy just with some sample data (as you can't define a boundaries here) or should we test the negative cases here at all? Probably it makes sense to create only such negative cases where we are trying to protect something explicitly. Otherwise would I be right to think we should just trust that what is not specified in policy is not allowed and so we should check only allowed actions.

I just wonder what would be the best approach in your opinion or if there are any established practices to this - I just can't find anything on this with google.